# Getting element content from another html element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this in my html page:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a href="www">
        LinkTitle
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the content of tag 'a' ("LinkTitle"), inside a javascript variable.

This was my approach:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var linkTitle = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("a").innerHTML;
alert(linkTitle);
```

And it returns null or undefined. Where did I go wrong and how could I fix this?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NtV7T/

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("a")[0]` ?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("a")` returns a list of `a` tags in the hmtml document.  which need to be iterated

Comment: Oh, stupid mistake, how couldn't I figure this out :( thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var linkTitle = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
```

As [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) returns an HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NtV7T/1/)

Answer (score 1):

var linkTitle = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;

getElementsByTagName returns array of elements

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that only the `document` element has the function `getElementsByTagName`.
All the other HTML elements do not have it.

You could use the `querySelector` like this:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var linkTitle = myDiv.querySelector("a")[0].innerHTML;
alert(linkTitle);
```

Comment: No, any element-nodes that can contain children are able to implement the `getElementsByTagName()` method; and `querySelector()` returns a single element-node (the first, and only the first) node that matches the selector.